# Does Sybase have a index seek operation (like SQL Server) in exection plan?

Tags: sql-server, sap-ase, seek, non-clustered-index

I am SQL Server devloper who is trying to optimize a Sybase query. I am trying to get a non cluster index to seek, but it keeps doing scan, just wanted to confirm is "seek" possible in Sybase if yes how to acheve a non cluster index seek?

I have a query like below (* is actually some 32 columns)

SELECT
    t.*
 FROM dbo.g1_positions t
 WHERE t.source_date = (select max(source_date) from g1_positions)

I have 3 non cluster index (no cluster index) on table as below

1. index named primary_key on columns entity_id, bgnref, retnum, source_date
2. index named idx_entdte on columns entity_id, source_date
3. index named idx_bgndte on columns bgnref, source_date

The inner query (which calculates max does index scan on idx_entdte), outer index by default does a table scan, if I force an index it does index scan and some thing extra which is decribe by 
"Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
        With MRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
"

My guess is this equivalent to "look up"  we have in SQL Server. 
After forcing index i do not see performance gain I was just wondering what can i do get performance improvement.

I can not do any changes on table like creating/droping/modifying index.

Just to give idea of lookup in SQL Server work.

Suppose we have table Employee with 4 records.

[image]

If a query uses non cluster index on Emp_id it will reach Leaf Node and to get actual data will use pointer to read actual data(row) on heap. This process using pointer is called LookUp

Comment: What do you expect it to seek on? The indexes have the source_date as the second or fourth column.

Comment: Agreed, without an index with `source_date` as the first column, there is no way the engine will be able to seek anything.

Comment: @ta.speot.is can something else be done so performance of query improves.

Comment: @Paciv any other trick to improve query performane?

Comment: You could put an index on source_date

Comment: @ta.speot.is :) Source system are not in my control.. we can not make any changes there.. some tirck at query level please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's possible!**

If it's not using it supposedly it's because the table scan is better.
That might be because the statistics are off! [Update them as well.](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands93.htm)

If needed, you can force the use of the index, for more info check [this example](http://www.rocket99.com/techref/sybase8685.html).

Comment: when I am forcing index it is doing "non cluster index scan". I have edited question to explain my scenario.

Comment: @Pritesh I'm a Sybase guy, can you explain me how the look up works on sql server pls.

Comment: added lookup detail to question. Please have a look.

Comment: The nonclustered (and the clustered as well) indexes do what you described in the image. Have you updated the statistics?

Comment: in cluster data (record) itself is on leaf node atleast in SQL Server is like that! so no need for lookup in cluster index. If I update statstics still non cluster index scan will happen?

Comment: If the defined index for the column(s) is a non clustered index, it will scan with that index allways. And yes, the clustered index works like in SQL Server.